# How do I reference successive components (button1, button2, etc.)?

Tags: c++, variables, c++builder, member

I need to get the number after the button to increment in a for loop. For example, button1 becomes button2, etc. I have tried appending a variable which increments but C++ Builder gives an error saying "Button is not a member of TMain." Is there any way to achieve the end goal or get around this?

Comment: Specify what exactly do you need. Do you need to make buttons with texts like "button1" "button2", or do you need to _make_ the buttons with _names_ like this, or do you need to _search_ for existing buttons with names like this?

Comment: Sorry, I want the caption to be like that so that it will get a word from a table and I have it in a loop so that the table keeps going to the next record but only the first button ever has a word inside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't construct new identifiers from others at run time. The compiler is correct that `Button` really isn't a member of your `TMain` class.

Instead, build the *string name* of the component you want, and then call your form's [`FindComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) method to get the component with that name.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
  std::string name = "Button" + IntToStr(i);
  TButton* button = dynamic_cast<TButton*>(this->FindComponent(name));
}
```

That requires that the buttons' `Name` properties be set accordingly.

Another solution is to forego the component names and put your objects in a proper container, like a `vector`. For example, you can override the `Loaded` method (which is where you can be sure all your form's components have been created) and fill a vector there:

```
void TMain::Loaded() {
  TForm::Loaded();
  this->m_buttons.push_back(Button1);
  this->m_buttons.push_back(Button2);
}
```

Now when you want to iterate over your buttons, you just iterate over the vector instead:

```
for (std::vector<TButton*>::const_iterator it = m_buttons.begin();
     it != m_buttons.end();
     ++it) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, you first solution got rid of my original problem but how do I assign data from a table to the caption of the buttons? I did have this, "Main->Button->Caption=Table2->FieldByName ("ItemName")->AsString;" but that only works for the one button called button. Also with that solution it says that variable button is declared but never used.

Comment: That's easy. I showed you how to get a pointer to the button control named "Button1" or "Button2" and store it in a variable named `button`. So use that variable to assign the caption of each button: `button->Caption = Table2->FieldByName("ItemName")->AsString`. Using my second example: `(*it)->Caption = ...`. I'm not sure what you mean by the "original problem." The only problem described in your question is the one about `Button` not being a member. I showed you that it doesn't need to be because you can access the buttons through other means.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! It's sorted I'll make sure to remember this :)